# Enyo buttons not responding to ontap events inside of leaflet popups

Tags: leaflet, enyo

I'm trying to use enyo in conjunction with leaflet. I am attempting to put a leaflet button inside of a leaflet popup, however the ontap callback never fires. Below I have included the code that instantiates the button. Any ideas on what I might be doing wrong? I have a feeling that I might not be instantiating the button correctly.

As an aside, there had been an issue with click event propagation being stopped by leaflet popups, but it has since be [resolved](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/commit/5a7420dd1a43474cccaa8cdefa4f324452d18f36).

EDIT: Here is more complete code, and a link to a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pwnosaurus/YPqpm/

```
enyo.kind({
    name: "mapContainer",
    rendered: function(){
        this.inherited(arguments);

        //Initialize the map
        this.map = L.map(this.id).setView([44.981313, -93.266569],13);
        L.tileLayer("http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png",
            {attribution: "Map data &copy; OpenStreetMap contributors"}
        ).addTo(this.map);

        //Initilize the marker and popup
        var mark = new L.marker([44.981014, -93.270520]).addTo(this.map);
        var popDiv = L.DomUtil.create("div");
        var pop = new L.popup();
        mark.bindPopup(pop);

        //Initilize the enyo button and control
        var ctrl = new enyo.Control({
            myHandler: function(){
                alert("The foo button was tapped");
            }
        });
        var button = new enyo.Button({
            name: "thefoobutton",
            content: "foo",
            ontap: "myHandler",
            owner: ctrl,
        });

        button.renderInto(popDiv);
        pop.setContent(popDiv);
    },

});
mapCont = new mapContainer();
mapCont.renderInto(document.body);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have implemented a workaround that puts a click handler on the leaflet popup which directly bubbles an ontap event on the button.

Code below, and in action here http://jsfiddle.net/pwnosaurus/uqcJJ/4/

```js
enyo.kind({
    name: "mapContainer",
    rendered: function(){
        this.inherited(arguments);

        //Initialize the map
        this.map = L.map(this.id).setView([44.981313, -93.266569],13);
        L.tileLayer("http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png",
            {attribution: "Map data &copy; OpenStreetMap contributors"}
        ).addTo(this.map);

        //Initilize the marker and popup
        var mark = new L.marker([44.981014, -93.270520]).addTo(this.map);
        var popDiv = L.DomUtil.create("div");
        var pop = new L.popup();
        mark.bindPopup(pop);

        //Initilize the enyo button and control
        var ctrl = new enyo.Control({
            myHandler: function(){
                alert("The foo button was tapped");
            }
        });
        var button = new enyo.Button({
            name: "thefoobutton",
            content: "foo",
            ontap: "myHandler",
            owner: ctrl,
        });

        //Add click handler
        //inspired by https://github.com/NBTSolutions/Leaflet/commit/466c0e3507cf0934a9d1441af151df2324a4537b#L2R129
        function forward(e){
            if (window.enyo && window.enyo.$ && e.srcElement && e.srcElement.id && window.enyo.$[e.srcElement.id]){
                    window.enyo.$[e.srcElement.id].bubble("ontap", e);
            }
        }
        this.map.on("popupopen", function (e){
            if (! e.popup.hasForwarder){ //Note: this check may not be needed. The L.DomEvent.on() seems to handle multiple adds of named functions
                L.DomEvent.on(pop._contentNode, "click", forward, this);
                e.popup.hasForwarder = true;
            }
        }, this);


        button.renderInto(popDiv);
        pop.setContent(popDiv);
        mark.openPopup();
    },

});
mapCont = new mapContainer();
mapCont.renderInto(document.body);
```

Comment: ctrl and button aren't really tied together in this example. Not sure why you don't just use a handlers block on the button to catch the ontap there.  Or, perhaps it would make more sense to have the button be owned by the map.  I think the fundamental problem is that it seems Leaflet's popup copies the HTML into its node.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you're not within an Enyo kind so, you don't want to set the owner.  If that's not it, can you provide a bit more context to where this code is?

Comment: just added a fiddle above!